# List files in order of size with certain name

Tags: linux

I have run 150 simulations. One did not run. I do not want to go into each folder to determine which one did not run. Is there a way to order all files named PKA.dump in order of their size (and also show me their location). There should be one file in one of the directories that is much less than the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Wheezy Debian, the following worked for me, to find the files `atom.in`, sorted largest to smallest:

```
ls -lSh $(find -name atom.in)
```

Another possibility is:

```
ls -lSh `find -name atom.in`
```

`$(find -name atom.in)` executes `find` to retrieve a list of all files named `atom.in`, with paths prepended. The list is then acted on by `ls -lSh`, which displays them once per line (`-l`), sorts them largest to smallest (`-S`), and prints the sizes in 'human-readable' format (`-h`).

Alternatively, if this doesn't work (apparently it fails hard on Ubuntu), as long as you have a good size threshold that divides 'good' simulations from 'bad' ones (say, 1600 bytes), this might work (change directories to the root of your simulation directory structure first):

```
find ./ -name 'PKA.dump' -size -1600c
```

Look up the `-size` flag in `man find` for more information on the available search options.  In particular, the leading hyphen indicates to search for files less than the specified size.  (For some reason, the code for bytes is `c`, not `b`.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming a successfull simulation yelds a file of at least 1600 bytes, the following command gives you a list of all files named `PKA.dump` and being smaller than this limit:

```
find -name PKA.dump -size -1600c
```

Hopefully you will be able to define an appropriate size limit (use `k` for kilobytes instead of `c`)

Alternatively,

```
find -name PKA.dump | xargs wc -l
```

will give you the list of all your `PKA.dump` files alongside with the number of lines in each file. If I understand correctly, any number less than 59 means trouble.

Comment: I dont think it does, all of my files are 1600bytes or so and this lists none of them

Comment: I changed the command, please recheck.

Comment: It still lists all of them.

Comment: not sure why, clearly one is missing something

Comment: there is one file that will not have 59 lines of text, is there a way to limit it to that

Comment: how does that line limit to 59?

Comment: It does not. It just prints the number of lines next to a file name. Also, the command assumes you don't have any spaces in those file names.

Comment: it appears its not working since the cluster I am using does some sort of compression. can it be edited for powershell?

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing where these PKA.dump files reside you can start find from the root directory. This will produce some error message and may take a while to run.

```
    find / -type f -name PKA.dump -ls | sort -n -k7
```